# Specifying type of argument dictionary keys in function definition itself

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

In TypeScript, I can do this:

```
interface Prop {
    prop_a? : number,
    prop_b? : string,
    prop_c? : string
}

function aa({prop_a, prop_b, prop_c}: Prop) {
    console.log('aa: ' + prop_a + ' ' + prop_b + ' ' + prop_c)
}
```

But then, why this is not allowed:

```
//A binding pattern parameter cannot be optional in an implementation signature.(2463)
function aaa({prop_a?: number, prop_b?: string, prop_c?: string}) {
    console.log('aa: ' + prop_a + ' ' + prop_b + ' ' + prop_c)
}
```

Also, specifying types of dictionary keys even if they are non-optional (that is removinb `?` from above snippet) is not allowed:

```
function aaaa({prop_a: number, prop_b: string, prop_c: string}) {
    console.log('aa: ' + prop_a + ' ' + prop_b + ' ' + prop_c)
}
```

Is it just language design choice or its indeed allowed, but am missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why this is not allowed

Because that's just not how the syntax is defined. You can do it inline, you just replace `Prop` with the definition of `Prop`:

```typescript
function aa({prop_a, prop_b, prop_c}: {prop_a?: number; prop_b?: string; prop_c?: string;}) {
    // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    console.log('aa: ' + prop_a + ' ' + prop_b + ' ' + prop_c)
}
```

> Is it just language design choice...

The types can't go where you showed them because in that location, they look like renamed destructured parameters (`prop_a` renamed to `number`, etc.; though you wouldn't be allowed to use `string` twice as a destructuring target name):

```js
function aaaa({prop_a: number, prop_b: string, prop_c: string2}) {
    console.log("number = " + number);
}
aaaa({prop_a: 42});
```

Also, it's more consistent for them to go in the same place as your original `Prop`.

Answer (score 0):

That's incorrect syntax, the proper way to do it is this:

```
function aaa({ prop_a, prop_b, prop_c }: { prop_a?: number, prop_b?: string, prop_c?: string }) {
```

This is incorrect because the type annotations are inside the destructuring assignment.

```
function aaa({prop_a?: number, prop_b?: string, prop_c?: string}) {
```

It is similar to:

```
const [foo: number, bar: string] = baz; // ! error

const [foo, bar]: [number, string] = baz; // good
```